# MPI_Barrier not work properly althought use fflush(stdout)

Tags: mpi

It doesn't print "-------------Hello------------" first, also "-----------------end------------------" last ???

```
    if (rank == 0) {
            printf("-------------------------HELLO-----------------------\n");
            fflush(stdout);
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("Process %i says hello\n", rank);
    fflush(stdout);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank==0)
            printf("--------------------END----------------------\n");

    MPI_Finalize();
```

Answer (score 2):

MPI gives no guarantees on the order, in which the standard output from different ranks appears. In fact, the MPI standard doesn't even guarantee that all ranks should be able to write to the standard output (it is possible to issue an environment inquiry with the `MPI_IO` key in order to find out which ranks could).

What happens is that many MPI libraries implement redirection of the standard output, either by sending it over network streams back to `mpirun`/`mpiexec` or by directly allowing each rank to write to the controlling terminal (if all ranks run on the same node). In both cases, although the order to the output lines coming from the same thread in each rank is preserved, the order in which text from different ranks or even from different threads of the same rank appears is undefined.

The only way to ensure that text output from different ranks will appear in a certain order is by explicitly sending the text to a single rank (e.g. to rank 0) in the form of MPI messages, combined with some form of synchronisation/flow control, e.g. token passing.